# When are matrix logarithms diagonal?

Tags: matrices, logarithms, inverse, orthogonal-matrices

Is this true: "$P$ is diagonal if and only if there exists a diagonal $\log P$"? This is the matrix logarithm. I just want to make sure of my reasoning.

If $\log P$ is diagonal, then $P$ is diagonal because
\begin{align*}
P &= \exp(\log P) \\
&= I + \log P + \frac{1}{2}(\log P)^2 + \cdots.
\end{align*}

On the other hand if $P$ is diagonal, then $\log P$ is diagonal because
$$
\log P = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\log P_{11} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \log P_{nn}
\end{array}
\right].
$$

On the second one, is the logarithm unique? What happens if I change $P$ to orthogonal? What about invertible?

Comment: Your question is not well posed, because matrix logarithm is not unique in general. When you say "$P$ is diagonal if and only if $\log P$ is diagonal", which $\log P$ are you referring to?

Comment: @user1551 yes I mentioned uniqueness but I have edited the question now to make it a little more clear. I am talking about any of them. What I care about is what kind of $P$ matrices can I look at that have at least one diagonal logarithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\log P$ is diagonal, clearly $P$ must also be diagonal, because $P=\exp(\log P)$ is a power series in $\log P$.

But then each diagonal entry of $P$ is the exponential of its counterpart $\log P$. Therefore, $P$ has a diagonal matrix logarithm if and only if $P$ is a diagonal matrix with an *entrywise nonzero* diagonal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "entry wise" distinction. That means that diagonal entries may be zero, but off-diagonal entries may not be, correct?

Comment: It means a diagonal matrix $P$ that has not any zero diagonal entries. That is, all diagonal entries of $P$ are **nonzero**, while all off-diagonal entries are zero.

Comment: should we change "nonzero" to "positive"?

Comment: If the ground field is real, yes. But I suppose the ground field is complex.